# Scrapy for eCommerce with Selenium Infinite Scroll, Help Returning Values

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am rather new to programming. I've done a few small projects on my own and have started getting into making webscrapers with Scrapy. I'm trying to make a scraper for Home Depot and have run into issues. The problem this is trying to solve is that the Home Depot webpage has javascript that only loads when you scroll down the page, so I added some code I found that scrolls down the page to reveal all the products so that it can grab the title, review count, and price of each product tile. Before adding this code, it was indeed scraping product info correctly; after adding it I originally had issues with the code only scraping the last page of results, so I moved some things around. I think being new I just don't understand something about objects in Scrapy and how information is passed, particularly the HTML I'm trying to get it to return values for in parse_product. So far this indeed opens up the page and goes to the next page, but it's not scraping any products anymore. Where am I going wrong? I have been struggling with this for hours, I'm taking a class in web scraping and while I've had some success it seems like if I have to do anything slightly off course it's a massive struggle.

```
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

class HdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hd'
    allowed_domains = ['www.homedepot.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Artificial-Greenery-Artificial-Flowers/N-5yc1vZcf9y?Nao='] #Add %%Nao= to end of URL you got from search or category


    def parse(self, response):
        options = Options()
        chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)#, chrome_options=options)
        p = 0 # The home depot URLs end in =24, =48 etc basically products are grouped 24 on a page so this is my way of getting the next page
        start_url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Artificial-Greenery-Artificial-Flowers/N-5yc1vZcf9y?Nao='

        while p < 25:
            driver.get(start_url + str(p))
            driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
            #sleep(2)
            scroll_pause_time = 1 
            screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
            i = 1

            while True: #this is the infinite scoll thing which reveals all javascript generated product tiles
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
                i += 1
                sleep(scroll_pause_time)
                scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
                if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
                    break
                self.html = driver.page_source    
            p = p + 24            

    def parse_product(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for products in resp.xpath("//div[@class='product-pod--padding']"):
            date = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y")
            brand = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__brand--bold']/text())").get() 
            title = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__product']/text())").get() 
            link = products.xpath(".//div//a//@href").get() 
            model = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='product-pod__model'][2]/text())").get()
            review_count = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__ratings-count']/text())").get()
            price = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='price-format__main-price']//span[2]/text())").get()
            yield {
               'Date scraped' : date,
               'Brand' : brand,
               'Title' : title,
               'Product Link' : "https://www.homedepot.com" + remove_tags(link),
               'Price' : "$" + price,
               'Model #' : model,
               'Review Count' : review_count
            }
```

Comment: some pages when you scroll then they may hide elements which are not visible (to use less memory and CPU) -  and then you get only last (visible) part. You may have to scrape elements after every scroll.

Comment: I don't see where you runs `parse_product`. it will not execute it automatically. Besides function like your `parse_product` is rather to use in some `yield Requests(url, parse_product)` to parese data from subpage, not from page which you get in `parse`. You should rather move code from `parse_product` into `parse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you runs `parse_product`. It will not execute it automatically for you. Besides function like your `parse_product` with `response` is rather to use it in some `yield Requests(supage_url, parse_product)` to parse data from subpage, not from page which you get in `parse`. You should rather move code from `parse_product` into `parse` like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    options = Options()
    chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)#, chrome_options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    p = 0 # The home depot URLs end in =24, =48 etc basically products are grouped 24 on a page so this is my way of getting the next page

    start_url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Artificial-Greenery-Artificial-Flowers/N-5yc1vZcf9y?Nao='

    scroll_pause_time = 1 
    screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web

    while p < 25:
        driver.get(start_url + str(p))

        #sleep(2)
        i = 1

        # scrolling
        while True: #this is the infinite scoll thing which reveals all javascript generated product tiles
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
            i += 1
            sleep(scroll_pause_time)
            scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
            if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
                break

        # after scrolling
        self.html = driver.page_source    
        p = p + 24            
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for products in resp.xpath("//div[@class='product-pod--padding']"):
            date = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y")
            brand = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__brand--bold']/text())").get() 
            title = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__product']/text())").get() 
            link = products.xpath(".//div//a//@href").get() 
            model = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='product-pod__model'][2]/text())").get()
            review_count = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__ratings-count']/text())").get()
            price = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='price-format__main-price']//span[2]/text())").get()
            yield {
               'Date scraped' : date,
               'Brand' : brand,
               'Title' : title,
               'Product Link' : "https://www.homedepot.com" + remove_tags(link),
               'Price' : "$" + price,
               'Model #' : model,
               'Review Count' : review_count
            }
```

But I would do other changes - you use `p = p + 24` but when I check page in browser then I see I need `p = p + 48` to get all product. Instead of `p = p + ...` I would rather use `Selenium` to click button `>` to get next page.

---

**EDIT:**

My version with other changes.

Everyone can run it without creating project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

class HdSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'hd'

    allowed_domains = ['www.homedepot.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Artificial-Greenery-Artificial-Flowers/N-5yc1vZcf9y?Nao='] #Add %%Nao= to end of URL you got from search or category

    def parse(self, response):
    
        options = Options()
        
        chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path) #, chrome_options=options)
        #driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        print(dir(driver))
        driver.maximize_window()
        
        scroll_pause_time = 1 

        # loading first page
        start_url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Artificial-Greenery-Artificial-Flowers/N-5yc1vZcf9y?Nao=0'
        driver.get(start_url)

        screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web

        #while True:        # all pages
        for _ in range(5):  # only 5 pages
        
            #sleep(scroll_pause_time)
            
            # scrolling page
            i = 1
            while True: #this is the infinite scoll thing which reveals all javascript generated product tiles
                driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollBy(0, {screen_height});")  
                sleep(scroll_pause_time)
                
                i += 1

                scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
                if screen_height * i > scroll_height:
                    break
        
            # after scrolling    
            resp = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
            
            for products in resp.xpath("//div[@class='product-pod--padding']"):
                date = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y")
                brand = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__brand--bold']/text())").get() 
                title = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__title__product']/text())").get() 
                link = products.xpath(".//div//a//@href").get() 
                model = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='product-pod__model'][2]/text())").get()
                review_count = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='product-pod__ratings-count']/text())").get()
                price = products.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='price-format__main-price']//span[2]/text())").get()
                yield {
                   'Date scraped' : date,
                   'Brand' : brand,
                   'Title' : title,
                   'Product Link' : "https://www.homedepot.com" + remove_tags(link),
                   'Price' : "$" + price,
                   'Model #' : model,
                   'Review Count' : review_count
                }
            
            # click button `>` to load next page
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next"]').click()
            except:
                break
                    
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})

c.crawl(HdSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I had tried putting everything in parse instead of parse and parse_product, but ended up with an issue where it was scraping products multiple times.. I probably nested something wrong.

Good catch on the 24 vs. 48 - I was doing a different category originally that showcased 24 products, but it needs to work for several different categories so the way you have set it up to have Selenium click through is much better. This is really simple looking and makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much, I'm really grateful for the help.

Comment: if you have the same product many times then maybe you should create list/dictionary with already added (`yielded`) items and check new item if it is already on this list - and skip it.